# I was executing Protractor Cucumber test with Jenkins, and in Cucumber Report last executed step is appearing In After step twice -

Tags: protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

I was executing Protractor Cucumber test with Jenkins, and in Cucumber Report last executed step is appearing In After step twice in report under Jenkins, Please suggest

here is my hook-

```
const { After, Before, AfterAll, Status } = require("cucumber");
import { browser, protractor } from "protractor";

Before({ timeout: 100 * 1000 }, async () => {
    await browser.get(config.baseUrl);
});

After(async function (scenario) {
    if (scenario.result.status === Status.FAILED) {
        const screenShot = await browser.takeScreenshot();
        this.attach(screenShot, "image/png");

            browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ESCAPE).perform();
            await helper.logoutFromApplication();

    }
});

AfterAll({ timeout: 100 * 1000 }, async () => {
    await browser.quit();
});
```

refer the report for the same-

[image]

Comment: Do you see this behavior in both failed and passed scenarios?

Comment: @supputuri in both cases After is appearing twice

Comment: This different scenario you have to refer the same in cucumber with java.